# _mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')

Tags: python, mysql

I use the Ontonotes DB tools, but I encounter a problem.

I read its document, and it say that this tool works well on mysql 5.0. However, I can't find this version. So, I install mysql 5.7. This problem appears, and the problem is like this:

```
python on/tools/init_db.py --init ontonotes localhost root ontonotes-release-4.0/
```

Initializing DB...

> /Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/on/**init**.py:525:
>   Warning: Unknown table 'ontonotes.tree'   cursor.execute("""drop table
>   if exists %s;""" % thing.sql_table_name)

```
create table tree
(
  id                  varchar(255) not null collate utf8_bin primary key,
  parent_id           varchar(255),
  document_id         varchar(255),
  word                varchar(255),
  child_index         int,
  start               int not null,
  end                 int not null,
  coref_section       int not null,
  syntactic_link_type varchar(255),
  tag                 varchar(255) not null,
  part_of_speech      varchar(255),
  phrase_type         varchar(255),
  function_tag_id     varchar(255),
  string              longtext,
  no_trace_string     longtext,
  parse               longtext,
  foreign key (parent_id)           references tree.id,
  foreign key (document_id)         references document.id,
  foreign key (syntactic_link_type) references syntactic_link_type.id,
  foreign key (part_of_speech)      references pos_type.id,
  foreign key (phrase_type)         references phrase_type.id,
  foreign key (function_tag_id)     references compound_function_tag.id
)
default character set utf8;
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "on/tools/init_db.py", line
>   81, in 
>       on.ontonotes.initialize_db(a_cursor)   File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/on/**init**.py", line
>   528, in initialize_db
>       cursor.execute(thing.sql_create_statement)   File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line
>   205, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
>   line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   _mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')

and there three table have been created:

```
create table ontonotes
(
   id varchar(255) not null primary key

)
default character set utf8;


create table subcorpus
(
  id varchar(255) not null primary key,
  base_dir varchar(255) not null,
  top_dir varchar(255) not null,
  root_dir varchar(255) not null,
  language_id varchar(255) not null,
  encoding_id varchar(255) not null,
  ontonotes_id varchar(255) not null

)
default character set utf8;

create table file
(
  id varchar(255) not null primary key,
  base_dir varchar(255) not null,
  physical_filename varchar(255) not null,
  document_id varchar(255) not null,
  file_type varchar(255) not null,
  subcorpus_id varchar(255) not null
)
default character set utf8;
```

I really don't know how to solve this problem, because I'm not familiar with mysql. Can someone help me, or give me a mysql 5.0 version (linux 64bit/mac 64bit)? Think you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The ontonotes authors choose myisam as engine, which ignores fks. They left them in the schema definitions because

"Even though MyISAM ignores foreign key constraints, we
do include them in table create statements to document them".
Page 10, offical Ontonnotes-v5 tool docu

Which is a problem if you use, for example innodb.
So the answer is : either use myisam or remove the fk constraints from *all* schema definitions.

i recommend importing the compressed dump included in the distributed bundle by the LDC